# XML valid last edit time from HTTP header response

Tags: php, date, sitemap

Good day!

I am trying to generate a sitemap with PHP.
I would like to optimize my code and therefore I was wondering if there is a way to determine the last time a file was modified by analyzing its header (I know it returns the last-modified but the time format is weird and also the position of this information in the $http_response_header array may change). I need something like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents($file, $context);
magicFunction($http_response_header); //returns last modified date in dd-mm-yyyy format
```

Any ideas? I found some solutions on StackOverflow but they all imply extra functions like filemtime or gmtime which I don't need having already the header response in hand.

Comment: Have you tried reading the info from the header? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this:

```
$pattern = '/^Last-Modified: (.+)$/';
$found = array_values( preg_grep( $pattern, $http_response_header ) );

$dateString = preg_replace( $pattern, '\1', $found[0] );
$lastModified = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $dateString ) );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/8mqmR)**</kbd>

With `preg_grep` (that filter an array using regex pattern) you get the desired header, then use `array_values` to ensure that desired header is in [0] key, then with `preg_replace` remove 'Last-Modified' part and convert it to a valid datetime string. At last, if you want, you can format it as you prefer.